# What's the VB.NET equivalent of async delegate in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda, async-await, c#-to-vb.net

I'm trying to convert the following extension method ([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/)) from C# to VB:

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                   int dop, Func<T, Task> body)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
        select Task.Run(async delegate {
            using (partition)
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                    await body(partition.Current);
        }));
}
```

The regular equivalent of `delegate` is `Sub()`, AFAIK, but I didn't expect it to work in this situation because of the `Async` keyword (and it didn't). So, I tried using `Function()` instead:

```vb
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function ForEachAsync(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T),
                                   dop As Integer, body As Func(Of T, Task)) As Task
    Return Task.WhenAll(
        From partition In Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
        Select Task.Run(Async Function() 'As Task '<-- see below.
                            Using partition
                                Do While partition.MoveNext()
                                    Await body(partition.Current)
                                Loop
                            End Using
                        End Function))
End Function
```

But this still doesn't compile and shows the following errors:

- At `WhenAll`:

  ```
  Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'WhenAll' can be called with these arguments:
      'Public Shared Overloads Function WhenAll(Of TResult)(tasks As IEnumerable(Of Task(Of TResult))) As Task(Of TResult())': Type parameter 'TResult' cannot be inferred.
      'Public Shared Overloads Function WhenAll(Of TResult)(ParamArray tasks As Task(Of TResult)()) As Task(Of TResult())': Type parameter 'TResult' cannot be inferred.
  ```
- At `Await body(partition.Current)`:

  > 'Await' may only be used in a query expression within the first
  >   collection expression of the initial 'From' clause or within the
  >   collection expression of a 'Join' clause.
- [Warning] at `Async Function()`: <sup>(it goes away if I add `As Task`)</sup>

  > Function '`<anonymous method>`' doesn't return a value on all code
  >   paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the
  >   result is used.

**What am I doing wrong? And what is the correct way to do this in VB?**

Comment: You can probaly do that (not tested) with `Task.WhenAll(Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop).Select(Function(p) (Task.Run(Async Function() Using p ... all the rest ... End Using End Function)` instead of `From partition In Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop) Select Task.Run(Async Function() ... all the rest ...)`

Comment: Of course *all the rest* is just `While p.MoveNext() Await body(p.Current) End While` :)

Comment: @Jimi That's weird! I'm not sure why I didn't think of that. But more strange is that it works even though both versions should do the same thing (right?). I'm I missing something? In any way, please post this as an answer :)

Comment: You might like this (because of the author :) [Async/Await FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asyncawait-faq/). See the *Where can’t I use “await”?* part, last point.

Comment: @Jimi That basically says the same thing that the second error above says. The part that I don't understand is how is that different from the C# code? On another note, if you'd like to post an answer, I would accept it because you did help me fix the problem.

Comment: All right, I'll write it down. I know that there are different implementation of the LINQ's query syntax in the two languages, which can be *subtle* at times. But since I don't have an *official* source, I don't have an official explanation about this difference. Well, these are two different languages, of course, but I don't know the real reason (or if there is one; even though, it may just be because of this expression: `Func(Of T, Task)` and the way is treated internally). I'll give it a look.

Comment: Well, the LINQ's query `Select` wants to return an `IEnumerable(Of TResult)` instead of an `IEnumerable(Of Task)`. You may just fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, the async Lambda can be expressed with a [delegate type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/delegate) or using the invocation operator [()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/invocation-operator) followed by the [=>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) token as a lambda operator to invoke an anonymous method:

```
Task.Run(async ()=> { } );
Task.Run(async delegate { } );
```

In VB.Net, an anonymous method can be invoked with a Lambda expression using  `Sub()` or `Function()`, both in-lined and with `Sub` / `End Sub`, `Function()` / `End Function` blocks:

```vb
Task.Run(Async Sub() [operation on captured variables])
Task.Run(Sub()
             [operation on captured variables]
         End Sub))

Task.Run(Async Function() [operation on captured variables])
Task.Run(Function()
             Return [operation on captured variables]
         End Function))
```

VB.Net's [LINQ to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/) doesn't allow to await in a `Select` clause, because:

> Await may only be used in a query expression within the first
> collection expression of the initial `From` clause or within the
> collection expression of a `Join` clause

It's referenced in Stephen Toub's [Async/Await FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asyncawait-faq/).

`Select Task.Run(Async Function() ... )` tries to return an `IEnumerable(Of TResult)` instead of an `IEnumerable(Of Task)`.

More in [Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/).

Conversely, [LINQ to Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-objects) - working with `IEnumerable/IEnumerable<T>` collections without other intermediate providers - does allow the async/await patter on a `Select` method:

```vb
<Extension>
Public Function ForEachAsync(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), dop As Integer, body As Func(Of T, Task)) As Task
    Return Task.WhenAll(
        Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop).
        Select(Function(p) (
                   Task.Run(Async Function()
                                Using p
                                    While p.MoveNext()
                                        Await body(p.Current)
                                    End While
                                End Using
                            End Function))))
End Function
```

The C# version of LINQ to SQL allows it instead.
Why, since the same rule should also apply to the C# implementation?

[The .NET Language Strategy](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-net-language-strategy/):

**C#**:

> We will keep growing C# to meet the evolving needs of developers and
> remain a state of the art programming language. We will innovate
> aggressively, while being very careful to stay within the spirit of
> the language.

**VB.Net**:

> We will keep a focus on the cross-language tooling experience,
> recognizing that many VB developers also use C#. We will focus
> innovation on the core scenarios and domains where VB is popular.

Thus, the [VB and C# Coevolution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/scottwil/2010/03/09/vb-and-c-coevolution/) asserted in 2010 has shifted: `C#` and `VB.Net` features update has been decoupled. Hence, given the new language strategy, `VB.Net` and `C#` don't *show roughly equal adoption* anymore.

Comment: Hey Jimi! Sorry for missing it - Congratulations and welcome to the 10k club! :)

Comment: @Visual Vincent  Hi there :) Thanks. What do you think about this? Has Link to Sql been *left behind* in VB.Net inplementation in some parts, compared to C# (well, right, flagship language and all...)? I've added a few more informations question-related. If you have some *insight*, let me know

Comment: I'm not much into Linq, but from what I gather doing an `Await` within a select should work fine in both languages. The error that the OP received (_"Await may only be used in a query expression (...)"_) doesn't make much sense as the `Await` is inside the method run by `Task.Run()` and not directly in the Linq expression, meaning it should have no effect on the expression whatsoever. Seeing as simply moving that piece code to a separate method (or even just a variable) works perfectly fine, it seems to me that the compiler error is, in this case, a bug.

Comment: Thanks, Jimi! You've been very helpful. @VisualVincent Yep, that's the part that doesn't make sense to me. Although the problem has been solved by using the method syntax (which I actually prefer) instead of the query syntax per Jimi's suggestion, your point is exactly why I didn't bother trying to switch to the method syntax before posting the question as I never have thought that it would make a difference!

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer to the question but, if it's truly asynchronous code, there's no need for partitioning the execution:

```vb
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function ForEachAsync(Of T)(
    source As IEnumerable(Of T),
    body As Func(Of T, Task)) As Task
    Return Task.WhenAll(        
        From item In source
        Select body(item))
End Function
```

Comment: I would've gone with this approach but it doesn't do the same thing. Partitioning allows you to limit the number of tasks that run simultaneously by running them as "chunks". Imagine executing web requests on a collection of 10K URLs and trying to start 10,000 tasks at the same time.

Comment: What's the runtime? If it's .NET Framework, the service point manager controls that.